# How do I convert a String in Array representation to a Numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a text file with each line that looks like this :

```
[204, -12, -1016, 1]
[208, -32, -976, 1]
[192, -24, -1008, 1]
```

I need to convert this into a Numpy array like this :

```
data = [[204, -12, -1016, 1], [208, -32, -976, 1], [192, -24, -1008, 1]]
```

such that calling `data[0]` will give `[204, -12, -1016, 1]` and calling `data[0][1]` will give `-12`

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: just read it on python list casting as int and cast to array with np.asarray()
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html

Comment: You should *fix whatever is generating this file*, but for now, you can probaly just use `np.array(list(map(eval, open('file.txt')))` or something to that effect

Comment: A more readable version without the eval: ```import numpy as np

l = []

with open("mine.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = list(map(int, line.strip().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(", ")))
        l.append(line)
print(np.array(l))```